# two linear layout takes half screen

Tags: android, xml

i am making a news app.all good exept the fact that my 2 linear layout overlaps each other.i tried with setting `width = o` and `weight = 1` on each child view but it give me this error error: '1dp' is incompatible with attribute `android:layout_weight` (attr) float.This is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1dp"
    tools:ignore="Suspicious0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/selection" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="Suspicious0dp">
    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/publicationDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android:layout_weight="1"` not `1dp`  
`layout_weight` is about size relative to the parent layout and has nothing to do with `dp` units

Answer (score 0):

you should add it like this for each linearlayout

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `android:layout_weight="1"` for each child and based on the parent layout orientation, If it is horizontal then child views should have `android:layout_width="0dp"` otherwise `android:layout_height="0dp"`.